# How to log images in middle of `train`

Tags: ray

It seems like you can only log data by return values from `train`. In many workflows, it might make more sense to directly save images in the middle of a train function (e.g. save images sampled by a generative model or from a vision-based MDP).

Is there a simple way to do this? One idea would be to try to find the log-directory and write to it directly, but would this have issues?

Comment: Can you provide a bit more information? For example, example code that you are using?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I'm guessing you're asking about using logging images in `Trainable:_train()`.

If you're not in local mode, within the trainable, you can access the `self.logdir` attribute to write images to. This should automatically be sync'ed back to your head node (if you're running remotely).

Comment: Thanks! Is this documented anywhere? Now that I look into it, I see that it's set in `Trainable.__init__`, but it's not clear if that's part of the public interface.

Comment: Oh, good point - I've made a PR and will get this merged soon; thanks!